# strategy.entry, why my qty formula doesn't get any result

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

i want to have a custom qty on my strategy.entry the formula is simple qty = 300 / (close - out3)

```
300 = amount of $
close = price when i take trade.
out3 = price of my SL based on a EMA.
```

so i did

`strategy.entry("buyy",strategy.long, qty = 300 / (close - out3))`

but my strategy display nothing seems like that come to the close call, cause if i'm doing 300 / out3 there is no problem.

I tried things like

```
     price = close
     strategy.entry("buyy",strategy.long, qty = 300 / (price- out3))
```

or

```
     price = close[1]
     strategy.entry("buyy",strategy.long, qty = 300 / (price- out3))
```

but nothing work everytime i tried to get the price around the time i take trade.
I'm new to pine script so, sorry if this is a basic question.

Answer (score 0):

In pinescript v5, when you declare your strategy, you must define the default_qty_type value, so that pinescript know what represent qty in your strategy.entry.

From the manual :

**default_qty_type** (const string) Specifies the units used for `default_qty_value`. 
Possible values are: 
**strategy.fixed** for contracts/shares/lots, 
**strategy.cash** for currency amounts, or 
**strategy.percent_of_equity** for a percentage of available equity. This setting can also be changed in the strategy's "Settings/Properties" tab. Optional. 
The default is strategy.fixed.

In your code it seems that the qty you calculate is cash. So you must use **default_qty_type=strategy.cash** in your strategy declaration.

Comment: hey thanks, but i my case that will not work cause i need to have the price of my asset at the moment of the trade is taken to calculate my qty. 
my quantity isn't cash it's the amount of the asset i should buy to respect my risk, the calcul is just : 300 / (entry price - stop loss price), my problem seems just to get the right entry price cause if i use : 300 / stop loss price, that work. but thats not the result i have to use, and i add the entry price nothing works anymore.

Comment: What does represent 300 in your code ?

Comment: 300 means the amounts of dollar i will risk on my trade, but i have then to adapt my leverage to get the right quantity, so on every trade i'll risk 300$ in this exemple but on every trade the qty i'll have to buy change and is defined by this calcul : 300 / (entry price - stop loss price).